# Problematic data export from Jasper server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am trying to export all data from Jasper server with

```
js-export.bat --everything --output-zip export.zip
```

but i am getting OutOfMemoryExceptions - we tuned up -Xmx and -Xms settings (i edit these parameters in js-export.bat). As we are running Jasper in medium Amazon instance we cannot add more memory (max allowed limit for -Xmx /XXPermSize is 1100m) because you cannot resize windows instance (only small/medium instance types are available).

I am not sure if it's possible to export selectively (e.g. only reports, then only datatypes, then...) in such way to do not break any dependencies. I tried to export all reports but then after import to another Jasper instance some reports were broken. As i am not Jasper expert, do you know what would be good way to achive full jasper export ?

I have following directories in Jasper server :

```
datatypes, datasources, dashboards, Input Controls, report output, reports
```